# Code executing time is incredibly long

Tags: java, sql, oracle11g

I'm trying to move data from one table to another(both table are same basically), the method that I'm using is `INSERT-SELECT`.

The problem that I'm facing is my java program seem like frozen there, but I can still force close it with `^C` easily, so I think it might be still alive but stuck for some reason.

This is my code which stuck in this problem

```
public String moveData(String sql, int day) {

    Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement stmt = null;
    int count;

    try {

        con = DriverManager.getConnection(DSN, Username, Password);
        stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        stmt.setInt(1, day);

        count = stmt.executeUpdate();

        return String.valueOf(count);

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("SQL exception: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();

        return "false";

    } finally {
        try {
            stmt.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

        try {
            con.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
```

and the SQL, executing it in SQL developer is really fast with 0.231 sec for 23k row of data

```
insert into Request_History  (customer_id, request_id, status, transaction_date, last_modified)
    SELECT customer_id, request_id, status, transaction_date, current_timestamp
    from Request_Log 
    where transaction_date <= (sysdate - NUMTODSINTERVAL(:1 ,'DAY'))
```

I see no problem on them, is there anything that I missed?

**Update**

Since there's no resolve on the program and SQL command, I'd like to change a way of thinking on the DB side.

Could anyone please tell me what kind of privileges do I need to execute my `INSERT-SELECT` SQL command on 11g without problem? because from what I can see that this command would only needs basic privileges such as `SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE` to execute.

Comment: Have you tried timing a simpler query either by debugging or even just logging? If you do just the select in java with no insert how does it compare?

Comment: @WilliamBurnham It's faster, only 0.018 sec since it's just select.

Comment: How many times is the method called? Can you change it such that the connection is passed to the method instead of being created for each query? Or iterate a `String[]` of sql instead of just one statement?

Comment: @WilliamBurnham this method is call for just once, and that's where I stuck with that `INSERT-SELECT`.

Comment: @user1055395 about 30 hrs.

Comment: Don't you have to use `?` for a Prepared statement  intead of `:1`? `NUMTODSINTERVAL(? ,'DAY'))`

Comment: @dnoeth yea, I just copy that out from Oracle because I'm looking at it

Comment: And the exact application wait time on Oracle record is 165276951626

Comment: does it scale with the amount of rows? i.e.: what happens when you call it with day=10,000 ?

Comment: and I assume that there is an index on transaction_date ? and what type is it? you might run into a full table scan if transaction_date has a different precision than sysdate

Comment: @EasterBunnyBugSmasher it's minus, so give it 10000 days will be back to 27 years ago and its pointless. The field type of `transaction_date` is `timestamp` and I don't have a index on it.

Comment: @EasterBunnyBugSmasher Doing full table scan is part of expectation, I need to copy all records which is created at X day(s) ago to another table.

Comment: one more thing I notice: try sending a commit

Comment: @EasterBunnyBugSmasher java's default value is auto-commit while executing each SQL.

Answer (score 0):

The time of the whole insert process depends on three factors:

- How many rows are in the query result set
- Is there any index, which can be used at query level (best for this would be an index on `Request_Log.transaction_date`
- Are there any constraints, indexes which have to be maintained during the insert phase (`Request_History` table)

Check the exec plan of the statement, to see if there's anything - worst things are full table scans. If you allowed, you can paste here the execution plan as well.

Comment: there's just 23k of rows of data, and SQL developer finished it with just 0.231 sec. And no, `transaction_date` is not indexed and performance impact is not significant from what I see so far. I don't think there is any constraint exist on that table since I can execute that SQL freely on SQL developer using application account.

Answer (score 0):

there is probably something wrong with the way you open your connection, something with you session parameters. You might not have enough undo space or another limiting factor. Maybe you can get a dba to check on it while you execute this over java vs. SQL Developer.

alter you statement to

```
create table Request_History_test  
as SELECT 
     customer_id, request_id, status, transaction_date, current_timestamp
   from 
     Request_Log 
   where 
     transaction_date <= (sysdate - NUMTODSINTERVAL(:1 ,'DAY'))
```

if this goes fast in contrast to your "insert select", then contact your DBA. There might be known issues with your undo space / redo logs. I'm not a DBA, so this answer is vague, I just had similar problems once.

oh, and check your dba_hist_sqlstat to see where the time is lost.

Comment: Well, your SQL have a error ORA-01027 replied from the SQL developer. And usually we don't give our APP account the CREATE_TABLE or DROP_TABLE permissions since it don't need them in the design.

Comment: Also I see nothing at `dba_hist_sqlstat` with `select * from dba_hist_sqlstat`, not even a row exist. Is there suppose to have something?

Comment: the SQL wasn't valid. I edited it, but not fully sure and I'm not at work to try it out.

Comment: probably something needs activated to see content in dba_hist_sqlstat. so far I've only worked with oracle databases that had it activated, so I can't help here.